# Cordova 5.0.0 android app can not connect to internet using android 4.0.0

Tags: android, cordova

I m developing the cordova applicatin using windows 7. The emulator can connect internet with browser but the app failed with network error

check the [link here]

Using the the latest cordova android 4.0.0 for devleopment

Cordova 5.0.0
Cordova-android 4.0.0

I have already added the whitelist as a new plugin to the cordova project. check the [link here](http://innotive.zhao.nu/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Capture_plugin.png)

My config.xml file is defined as below, the access is given to all URL. I really dont know where it could go wrong. Please advice.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.vs.VSMF"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>VSMF</name>

    <description>
        VSMF project template.
    </description>

    <author href="" email="dong_dh@hotmail.com">
        Hua Dong
    </author>

    <!--
        Enable individual API permissions here.
        The "device" permission is required for the 'deviceready' event.
    -->
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <!-- <preference name="phonegap-version"      value="3.4.0" /> -->      <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="disallowOverscroll"         value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="false" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="false" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay"          value="60000" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="17" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
    <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <!-- Plugins can also be added here. -->
    <!--
        <gap:plugin name="Example" />
        A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins
    -->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.

        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
    -->
    <access origin="*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <!--
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

   </widget>
```

in the androidmenifest.xml file , the permission is also given

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: You have an Network Error when you try to do something specific in the app?

Comment: Yes, my app will need log in via the linkedin KPI. Also when the app starts, it will initiate the communication towards the server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so Sorry, do you add Content-Security-Policy meta tag?if you set Content-Security-Policy meta incorrect,it may cause this problem.

Comment: What makes you think that OP's question is a plugin issue?

Comment: Please read the question carefully, the plugin is already installed. thanks

Comment: @MingZhao.Sorry,do you add  Content-Security-Policy meta tag?

Comment: Thanks Van, it helps by adding the CSP in the index.html header. At least i get the linkedin api working. There still some communication error with my own server.

Comment: Could you expand on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Whoever comes in 2021 with the same issue, please add proper content security policy meta tag. I'd also same issue in ionic 5.5 cordova 9 in android 5.x.x devices. See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32606039 .

Answer (score 46):

Answer is this:

[Ajax requests fail after upgrading to Cordova 5.0 + cordova-android@4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060534/ajax-requests-fail-after-upgrading-to-cordova-5-0-cordova-android4-0)

You need the [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

```
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Then add the following in your `config.xml`:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: I actually think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Add `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />` to config.xml if you use Phonegap Build (PB)

Answer (score 3):

CIF's answer is correct, but for the sake of anybody else viewing this, I figured I'd post the default allow-intent configuration that is generated using `cordova create`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```