# Phonegap Ajax request not executing

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have an Android app that I have been building on phoengap. I upgraded to the newest version on phoengap build:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
```

And my config looks like this:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro" version="5.2.1">

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />

    <name>Beer Portfolio</name>
    <description>Know Your Beer</description>
    <author href="http://www.beerportfolio.glass" email="mike@beerportfolio.glass">Mike</author>
    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" source="npm"/>
    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" source="npm" />


    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  - lower 4s -->
    <icon src="icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch - 5-5s -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPhone6-6+ -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

    <!-- Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" source="npm"/>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.3" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm"/>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification" />

    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

When I try and execute a button to log in now, it never executes the ajax request. My html looks like this:

```
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m7">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <img src="img/logo.png">

                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="col s12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input id="email" type="text" class="validate">
                                    <label for="email">Username</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input id="example" type="password" class="validate">
                                    <label for="example">Password</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                        <a id="login" class="waves-effect waves-light white-text btn orange">Login</a>

                        <a id="register" class="orange-text" style="float: right;" href="register.html">Register</a>



                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!--  Scripts-->

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/home.js"></script>



</body>
```

And my JS looks similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    //check if user has already logged in once
    if (localStorage.getItem("userID") != null) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("userID", localStorage.getItem("userID"));
        window.location.replace("stats.html");
    }

    //if user has logged in go to stats page

    $("#login").click(function () {
        var u = $('#email').val();
        var p = $('#example').val();
        alert("test1");
        $.get("http://www.beerportfolio.glass/app_login2.php", {
                ex1: example1,
                ex2: example
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                alert("test2");
                if (data.status == "no") {
                    alert("test3");
                    mixpanel.track("Wrong User Name or password");
                    alert("Wrong username and password");
                } else {
                    alert("test4");
                    mixpanel.track("User logged In");
                    //todo: store user name
                    mixpanel.identify(data.userID);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("userID", data.userID);
                    //redirect to statistics page
                    window.location.replace("stats.html");
                }
            });

    });
```

When I execute in my browser on my desktop all works perfect. But when I execute after building with phonegap build, It only shows "test1" on execute which shows its not executing the ajax call.

```
});
```

Comment: try adding <access origin="*" /> to your config file

Comment: trying that now, thanks. Whats it do?

Comment: @Diptox that did not work

Comment: ow , let me search for another solution

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30066390/5365770

Answer (score 1):

@Mike,
you have two options, rollback before 4.0 or move forward.

To move forward, you need to read deeper into documentation. You need to add header information in your HTML page.

See: [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html).
or the [npm version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

Here is an example of what you need to add to your webpage from the documentation:

`<!-- Allow requests to foo.com --> <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' foo.com">`

Even more details are available at:
 [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
See #10

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

Recently i just read that all http requests must be https... take a look at https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ios/ios9

Comment: Just to clarify: the https requirement is iOS 9 only right now.

Comment: any CA you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

The whitelist plugin has moved out of cordova/phonegap. You need to add it  yourself. A good choice is [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is now phonegap does not allow cors ajax if you did not explicitly allow the origing like this:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

The fastest solution is to compile against an older phonegap version. For example just add this in your config.xml

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

recently i had the same problem, i just change my config.xml and it works, i use ajax, my config.xml is like this.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" version="1.2.0" source="npm"  />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" /> 
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="1.0.1" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" version="1.1.1" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" version="1.0.1" source="npm"  />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" version="1.1.1" source="npm"  />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="3.0.0" source="npm"  />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" version="1.0.1" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="2.1.0" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" version="1.2.0" source="npm"  />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-sms" version="1.0.4" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" version="4.0.2" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.5.0"  />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" version="0.2.12" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.plugin" version="5.0.4" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
```

my request:

```
$.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {$('#div_carga').show();},
            complete: function(){$('#div_carga').hide();},
            type: "post",
            url:"https://www.example.net/get_form.php",
            data:{id:id},
            success: function(datos){
                $("#obten").remove();
                $("#contenidoForm").append("<div id='obten' name='obten'></div>");
                $('#prospectos').html(datos);
            }
        });
```

if i use httpRequest also it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.get("http://www.beerportfolio.glass/app_login2.php", {
                ex1: example1,
                ex2: example
})
```

Check your get request params.

`example1` and `example` are undefined.