# Failed to send telemetry in ionic cordova mobile app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, azure-application-insights

I want to track all errors in a mobile app using Application Insights(https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-ms-appinsights plugin). but, I get following error message when I call `appInsights.trackException` function:

```
Failed to send telemetry:
    {"itemsReceived":1,
        "itemsAccepted":0,
        "errors":[
        {
        "index":0,
        "statusCode":400,
        "message":"109: Field 'method' on type 'StackFrame' is required but missing or empty. Expected: string, Actual: "}
        ]
    }
```

If I call `appInsights.trackPageView` function then it works fine with status code 200(OK).

I have also tried this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066390/5251807) solution. but, It does not work for me.

Version info:

Cordova version: 8.0.0

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

Node: v6.11.4

npm: 5.5.1

Comment: With what parameters are you calling `appInsights.trackException`?

Comment: I am calling with only one parameter as : appInsights.trackException(exception);